# Hide mah apps metro Hamburger Menu button in wpf

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

i am using Hamburger menu in my application. it is possible to hide hamburger menu button.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `HamburgerVisibility` property to `Collapsed` or `Hidden`:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu HamburgerVisibility="Collapsed" ... />
```

Comment: there is no property name with "HamburgerVisibility"

Comment: On the HamburgerMenu? There certainly is. What control and what version are you using?

Comment: i found the issue, i have two application both are using mah apps hamburger one is accepting  "HamburgerVisibility" property and another one is not accepting,i cross checked the version of dll both are different